# How to display headup notification with flutter local_notification package?

Tags: flutter

I successed to display notification in the notification center, but I havn't a headup banner display when I receive the notification.

here is my reproduce code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: _showNotification,
                child: new Text('Show Notification'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Future _showNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        showWhen: true);
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x');
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Your Notification Detail"),
          content: Text("Payload : $payload"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Android devices that notifications will only in appear in the tray and
> won't appear as a toast aka heads-up notification unless things like
> the priority/importance has been set appropriately. Refer to the
> Android docs
> (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up)
> for additional information.

Might be helpful to add this setting to [AndroidManifest.xml:](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<activity
    android:showWhenLocked="true"
    android:turnScreenOn="true">
```